# Generating random numbers in conditions

Tags: c

I'm trying to generate three random numbers in three conditions and the three numbers must be from 0 to 100:

1. an odd number
2. an even number
3. a number larger than 50

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    num1 = rand() % 100;
    while (num1 % 2 != 0) {
        num1 = rand() % 100;
    }
    num2 = rand() % 100;
    while (num2 % 2 == 0) {
        num2 = rand() % 100;
    }
    num3 = rand() % 100;
    while (num3 > 50) {
        num3 = rand() % 100;
    }
    printf("your numbers\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", num1, num2, num3);
    return 0;
}
```

the compiler answers me:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'srand' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  srand(time(NULL));
```

and I do have stand in the requirements of the school:

- it must be in loops
- I cannot use `break` nor `TRUE` nor `FALSE`

Comment: What's your question? Does this code work? If not, what is the problem with it?

Comment: @interjay his question is how to generate three random numbers between 0 to 100, one an odd number , two an even number and 3, above 50.

Comment: @Nina And does this code already do that? Does it fail on one or all three? etc.

Comment: the code fails at the line 7,9 and 15

Comment: `rand() % 100` cannot produce `100`, Is the range `0` to `100` inclusive?

Comment: Add `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: Change the third loop tp `while (num3 <= 50)`

Comment: "...it must be in loops..." - ah, the old Teach Them To Do The Wrong Thing ploy.

Answer (score 7):

Your `srand()` issue is simply because you haven't included `stdlib.h`, where that call (and `rand()` for that matter) is declared.

In any case, there's no real need to use a loop while discarding "invalid" numbers, you can use *math* for this :-) <sup>(a)</sup>

Assuming 0 to 100 *inclusive:*

```
num1 = rand() % 50 * 2 + 1  // 1, 3, 5, ..., 99
num2 = rand() % 51 * 2      // 0, 2, 4, ..., 100
num3 = rand() % 50 + 51     // 51, 52, ..., 100
```

For `num1`, the `%` gives a value `0..49` which, when doubled and incremented, gives you an odd number in the desired range. The second one is similar but with the range expanded slightly since there are even numbers at both ends. The third simply gives a number `0..49` which maps to `51..100` when `51` is added.

Similar results can be obtained if the range is only half-open (`0..99` inclusive):

```
num1 = rand() % 50 * 2 + 1  // 1, 3, 5, ..., 99
num2 = rand() % 50 * 2      // 0, 2, 4, ..., 98
num3 = rand() % 49 + 51     // 51, 52, ..., 99
```

---

If, for some bizarre reason it *has* to use a loop (despite the inefficiencies), you have some problems with the conditions you use - they're basically all the wrong sense. In other words, you want (for example) the first loop to run while the number is *even* so that it will eventually produce an odd number.

You should be able to use something like the following. Each block consists of initialising the variable to a value that will force the loop to start then the loop that continues until a value with the desired properties is found:

```
int num1 = 0;             // even forces loop entry
while ((num1 % 2) == 0)   // wait for odd
    num1 = rand() % 100;

int num2 = 1;             // odd forces loop entry
while ((num2 % 2) == 1)   // wait for even
    num2 = rand() % 100;

int num3 = 1;             // 50 or less forces loop entry
while (num3 <= 50)        // wait for 51+
    num3 = rand() % 100;
```

All of these limit the range of potential values to `0..99` inclusive, If you want to include `100`, simply change the expressions to be `rand() % 101`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I'm actually not a fan of these sorts of limitations when set by educators. They're actually teaching *inefficient* ways to code. It would be far better if it was something that was a lot harder to do with a simple mathematical operation (like ensuring the number was neither `11`, `17`, `43` nor `97`).

I suspect you *could* find a mathematical way to detect that but it would be far easier just to use a series of conditionals. Now I'm just waiting for someone to show me up by providing the mathematical formula for detecting those four :-)

Comment: my task requires a loop for example if the first condition is false it must keep generaiting numbers until the it generates a number that stands in condition

Comment: @loaykher, that wasn't a requirement listed in your question and, in any case, it's totally unnecessary. Will add an addendum.

Comment: For  neither 11, 17, 43 nor 97 I'd use an array and choose from that.

Comment: Aside: With [0-100] there are 50*50*50.  So only one `rand() % (50*50*50)` needed.

Comment: How about: `int x = rand() % 96; return x + (x >= 11) + (x >= 17-1) + (x >= 43-2) + (x >= 97-3);` Not exactly mathermatical, but should generate jumpfree code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: `rand() % (50*50*50)` would not produce good results on system where `RAND_MAX < 125000`. The minimum value for `RAND_MAX` is `32767`, hopefully only so low on 16-bit systems.

Answer (score 2):

There are some mistakes in the posted code:

- a missing `#include <stdlib.h>`
- the first test should be `while (num1 % 2 == 0)`
- the second test should be `while (num2 % 2 != 0)`
- the third test should be `while (num3 <= 50)`

Here is a modified version with loops but without looping :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
    int num1, num2, num3;

    srand(time(NULL));  /* or better randomness with srand(clock()); */

    num1 = 1 + rand() % 50 * 2;  /* 1, 3, ..., 99 */
    while (num1 % 2 == 0) {
        num1 = rand() % 100;
    }
    num2 = rand() % 50 * 2;  /* 0, 2, ..., 98 */
    while (num2 % 2 != 0) {
        num2 = rand() % 100;
    }
    num3 = 51 + rand() % 49; /* 51, 52, ..., 99 */
    while (num3 <= 50) {
        num3 = rand() % 100;
    }
    printf("your numbers\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", num1, num2, num3);
    return 0;
}
```

For those interested, both **gcc** and **clang** detect that the first 2 loops can be eliminated, but not the third as they do not make the assumption that `rand()` return a non negative number: https://godbolt.org/z/ucpV-y

Comment: Wow, GCC recognizing that awful rejection loop and optimizing it is surprising. Somebody must have put that in just for this common bad beginner code. I think, instead of optimizing it, GCC should print a diagnostic saying “No, no, please don’t do that, just don’t.”

Comment: Yes, the loops are useless (even the third) since you generate valid numbers in the first `rand()` call for each. I suspect, if a student handed in something that made the loops superfluous but didn't actually remove them, I'd probably take off marks for that :-)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: actually, it is just a side effect of range and pattern propagation: `x * 2` has the low bit clear and `x * 2 + odd_constant` has the low bit set. The third loop cannot be optimized out because since `rand()` is defined as returning an `int`, `rand() % 49` has a potential range of `-48..48`, do `num3` is not necessarily > 50.

Comment: @paxdiablo: it depends if you have a sense of humor :). The student did write loops as requested, but optimized them by astutely computing a valid random initial value. Doing this without prior knowledge of the professor is risky, as per the famous Niels Bohr urban legend: https://io9.gizmodo.com/at-last-the-field-of-physics-has-its-own-version-of-th-5942429

Comment: @chqrlie, yes, I seem to recall reading that someone handed in a literary assignment on Fight Club with just the text "The first rule about Fight Club is that you don't talk about Fight Club". They got an A but examiner made it clear anyone else (presumably anyone without his sense of humour) probably would have failed them :-) I had not read that Bohr one.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I like your example. Another one is handing in a blank sheet in response to this question: *What is audacity?*

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include <stdlib.h>` to get rid of this warning.

However, there's a bigger problem with your code: you have all the conditions inverted.

This will loop until the number is odd:

```
while (num1 % 2 != 0) {
```

This will loop until the number is even:

```
while (num2 % 2 == 0) {
```

And this will loop until the number is less than or equal to 50:

```
while (num3 > 50) {
```

To fix that, simply invert the conditions:

```
while (num1 % 2 == 0) { /* until we get an even number */
/* ... */
while (num2 % 2 != 0) { /* until we get an odd number */
/* ... */
while (num3 <= 50) { /* until num3 is greater than 50 */
```